# How to build a movie database with wordpress?

Tags: database

I'm looking for a plugin to build a movie database like [Popcritics](http://popcritics.com/movies)

The plugin would permits me to add custom info (like [CustomPress](http://premium.wpmudev.org/project/custompress) can do) about a movie.

Ultimately, the plugin could permit users to register for saving favorites movies.

Do you know of one ?

Comment: What does this mean? - "permit users to register for saving favorites sites" Also, why not just use CustomPress? It appears to do everything you need. Just create a custom post type with the custom fields you need for movies.

Comment: @TravisPflanz I wanted to say 'movies' not sites

Answer (score 5):

I'd point you to the much-cited Justin Tadlock ["Using custom taxonomies to create a movie database"](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2009/06/04/using-custom-taxonomies-to-create-a-movie-database) as a good place to start. His example is Popcritic.

The saving favorites would probably require a different plugin, but such is the nature of WordPress.