# Custom Fields link to other pages, not search

Tags: custom-taxonomy, custom-field, links

I am attempting to create a website, which has a similar taxonomy system to IMDB, but instead of Movies, it is referencing Musicians. I have created a custom post type for Artists, with a few custom field called Record Label on it.

I am stuck because when I create this custom field and click on the link it produces, it takes me to a search page, rather than to a page made for that Record Label. Is there anyway I can bypass the search section, and link to the Record Label page in particular?

And, as bonus question, I would also like the relationship between the Movie and the Actor to show up on both pages, rather than on just one or the other. For example, if I said that an Artist was signed to a label, I would like the label page to automatically update the fact that it has signed the band.

So far, I have created Custom Post Types, for both Artist and Label, but I am having trouble linking the two together. Am I going about this the wrong way? I know I am probably missing something obvious, but I cannot find an answer.

Thanks for your help,
Joseph.

Answer (score 0):

Start by reading ["Using custom taxonomies to create a movie database"](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50437/how-to-build-a-movie-database-with-wordpress/50441#50441). You'll learn about custom post types and custom taxonomies and how to use those to hook posts together.

It's possibly that your Labels should be a custom taxonomy rather than a post type, but maybe not. If you can use a custom taxonomy for setting up relationships, that's ideal, but if not there are some plugins that can help.

Particularly, take a look at [Advanced Custom Fields](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) which has a relationship field or the [Posts 2 Posts](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/posts-to-posts/). I've used the first and had very good luck with it. I haven't use the second, but it's got a good reputation.